# ABP IRepository<TEntity> from Service Provider is empty

Tags: .net-6.0, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have a Console app that depends on different projects (I use **DependsOn()** notation) in my console module.

```
[DependsOn(
   typeof(AbpAutofacModule),
   typeof(SecondProjectModule),
   // Other dependencies
)]
public class MyConsoleAppModule...
```

Then, my console app calls a method in the second project and there I try to get an IRepository using the service provider like this:

```
using (var scope = SecondProjectModule.GetScope())
{
    using (var uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWorkManager>().Begin())
    {
        var repo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IReadOnlyRepository<MyEntity>>();
        return ... // LINQ here
    }
}
```

But the repo is empty with ***null*** for DbContext and other properties.
If I call this method using my WebApp project it runs perfectly.

The GetScope() method in the SecondProjectModule is very simple:

```
public static IServiceScope GetScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null)
{
    var provider = serviceProvider ?? _serviceProvider;

    return provider?
       .GetRequiredService<IHybridServiceScopeFactory>()
       .CreateScope();
}
```

Not sure where is the issue here since the dependencies from my ConsoleApp projects seems to be fine.

Comment: If the repo is null that means it can't find a registered instance to return 
Did `scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWorkManager>()` also return null? and did you try with another service and check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of repository is located under **EfCore** or **MongoDB** layers of your second module.

Web application works fine because it has dependency for db integration layer (EfCore or MongoDB) which contains the implementation of repositories.

Assuming your *SecondProjectModule* is an Application Service, you need a reference to, and depends on db integration layer of that module (EfCore or MongoDB) aswell.

You can check the [docs about layering](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Best-Practices/Module-Architecture#layers-packages) and notice that application service doesn't have any dependency to EfCore or MongoDB.